# how to acess user session in sfDoctrineRoute with symfony?

Tags: php, session, routes, symfony1, doctrine

how to acess user session in sfDoctrineRoute with symfony ?

```
var_dump(sfContext::getInstance()->getUser());
```

returns NULL

i cant access current user session in routing

[Accessing user session from a custom routing class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455817/symfony-accessing-user-session-from-a-custom-routing-class) = bad response

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? can you give us a little more background? sfContext::getInstance() in a lot of cases isn't the anwser... :-)

Comment: i dont want to pass informations in the url to retrieve the routing object in my controller's action.
i have make a custom routing class and i cant retrieve user session

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `sfDoctrineRoute::setQuery()` method from your controller, and generate a query using its `sfUser` reference and, for example, the user credentials it contains:

```
protected function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $query = Doctrine::getTable('Foo')
    ->createQuery('f')
    ->whereIn('f.access_level', $this->getUser()->getCredentials())
  ;

  $this->getRoute()->setListQuery($query);

  $this->foo_list = $this->getRoute()->getObjects();
}
```

Hope it helps.

PS: you should [ALWAYS avoid calling sfContext::getInstance()](http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/).